# Analyticity of solutions to Schrödinger's equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, quantum-mechanics, schrodinger-operators, analytic-functions

Take Schrödinger's equation on $\mathbb{R}$, $i\partial_t\psi(x,t)=H\psi(x,t)$. Assume that $\psi(x,0)$ has compact support. Using known integral formulas for the propagators, it is fairly straightforward to verify that

- in the free case ($H = p^2$), $\psi(x,t)$ extends to an entire function of $x$ for all $t\neq 0$,
- in the harmonic oscillator case ($H=p^2 + x^2$), $\psi(x,t)$ extends to an entire function of $x$ for all $t\notin \pi\mathbb{Z}$.

In these cases, the cause seems to be that at the specified times, the integral kernel is a holomorphic function of two variables. Is there a way to see such behavior more generally, for example, what about the hamiltonians $p^2 + x^2 + \lambda x^4$ or $\sqrt{p^2 + m^2}$? I can't find any references for this, the closest question on this site is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219928/real-analyticity-of-solution-of-heat-equation), but it deals with analyticity in time. I'm also allowing for the possibility that the formulation of the problem I'm implying is not quite right: for example, we may wonder only about real analyticity in $x$, or perhaps restrict the initial condition to be also smooth... Anything along these lines will do.

If anyone is wondering, I stumbled upon this question because showing a result like this is one way of seeing that the Schrödinger equation (for given $H$) has non-causal behavior, much like the heat equation.