# Do we lose any solutions when applying separation of variables to partial differential equations?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

For example, consider the following problem
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},\hspace{0.5cm} u(x,0)=f(x),\hspace{0.5cm} u(0,t)=0,\hspace{0.5cm} u(L,t)=0$$
Textbooks (e.g., [Paul's Online Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SeparationofVariables.aspx)) usually apply separation of variables, assuming that $u(x,t)=\varphi(x)G(t)$ without any explanation why this assumption can be made.

Do we lose any solutions that way given that there are functions of two variables $x$ and $t$ that are not products of functions of individual variables?

Separation of variables gives the following solution when we consider only boundary conditions:
$$u_n(x,t) = \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)e^{-k\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2t},\hspace{0.5cm}n=1,2,3,\dotsc.$$

The equation is linear, so we can take a superposition of $u_n$:
$$u(x,t) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)e^{-k\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2t}$$
where $B_n$ are found from the initial condition:
$$B_n = \frac{2}{L}\int\limits_0^Lf(x)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx,\hspace{0.5cm}n=1,2,3,\dotsc.$$

Are there solutions $u(x,t)$ that cannot be represented this way (not for this particular pde but in general)? What happens in the case of non-linear equations? Can we apply separation of variables there?

Comment: It all depends what you mean by *solution*. In examples like the one you gave, the method works fine for weak solutions in an $L^2$ setting, but for example you won't be able to get the classical solution of the heat equation with $u=0$ initially this way (see here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82408/non-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-the-heat-equation ).

Comment: I think the accepted answer provides somewhat simplistic view on the problem. I suggest you to read Sec. 2 of arXiv:1412.7052 where exactly your issue is discussed.

Comment: It seems implausible that the answer is "yes" for nonlinear PDEs. As an analogy, consider the ODE $(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 = 4y$. The general solution is $y = (x + C)^2$ for an arbitrary parameter $C$, but $y = 0$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Consider your purported solution $u(x,t)$ at fixed $t$, i.e., think of it as a function only of $x$. Such a function can be expanded in a complete set of functions $f_n (x)$,
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n} u_n f_n (x)
$$
What happens when you now choose a different fixed $t$? As long as the boundary conditions in the $x$ direction don't change (which is the case in your example), you can still expand in the same set $f_n (x)$, so the only place where the $t$-dependence enters is in the coefficients $u_n $ - they are what changes when you expand a different function of $x$ in the same set of $f_n (x)$. So the complete functional dependence of $u(x,t)$ can be written as
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n} u_n (t) f_n (x)
$$
Thus, when we make a separation ansatz, we are not assuming that our solutions are products. We are merely stating that we can construct a basis of product form in which our solutions can be expanded. That is not a restriction for a large class of problems. As is evident from the preceding argument, this goes wrong when the boundary conditions in the $x$ direction do depend on $t$ - then we cannot expand in the same set $f_n (x)$ for each $t$. For example, if the domain were triangular such that the length of the $x$-interval depends on $t$, the frequencies in the sine functions in your example would become $t$-dependent.

Comment: Just to make the connection to @ducksforever's answer. When the domain changes, this corresponds to the Hilbert space $V$ is changing, i.e. $t$ enters into the $f_n$'s if $V$ depends on $t$. More specifically, for your example, $V = \{ f \mid f : [0,L] \to \mathbb R \}$ and a triangular domain means a linear shrinking of $L$ depending  on $t$. Hope I got it right.

Comment: @StefanH - yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 16):

As you correctly noted, in the end we write our solution as a superposition of separable solutions, so the right question really 'can we express every solution to our PDE as a sum of separable solutions'?

A thorough answer to this question requires a little linear algebra. What we want to do is find a set of functions $\{\varphi_n(x): n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ so that for each time $t$ write our solution $f$ as $f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \varphi_n(x) G_n(t)$ where the $G_n$ are just some coefficients which are allowed to depend on time. Not only does such a set of functions exists, we can actually find a set of these functions through the process of separation of variables.

Let's consider the heat equation again. When we separate variables, we reduce the situation to two ODEs:

$$G'(t) = EG(t), \varphi''(x) = \frac{E}{k}\varphi(x) $$ where $E$ is some unknown constant.

Remember that the differentiation is linear: that is, for functions $f$ and $g$ and constants $a,b$ we have $\frac{d}{dx}(af(x)+bg(x)) = a\frac{df}{dx} + b \frac{dg}{dx}$. What this means is that our two ODEs are eigenvalue problems: we have an eigenvalue problem for the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ with eigenvalue $E$, and an eigenvalue problem for the operator $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ with eigenvalue $\frac{E}{k}$.

We need the eigenvectors of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ (i.e. the solutions to our $\varphi$ ODE) to form a basis for our space of functions. Luckily, there is a theorem that does exactly this sort of thing for us.

[Spectral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem):

> Let $V$ be a Hilbert space and $T: V \to V$ a (sufficiently nice) self-adjoint map. Then there exists an orthonormal basis for $V$ which consists of eigenvectors for $T$.

In order to make sense of this, we need one final ingredient: an inner product. This is just something which generalises the familiar `[dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)' in three dimensions. The inner product of two functions $f$, $g$ is a real number, defined as
$$\langle f,g\rangle := \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)g(x) dx$$.

A basis of functions $\{f_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is called *orthonormal* if $\langle f_n, f_n \rangle = 1$ and $\langle f_n, f_m \rangle = 0$ when $n \neq m$.

Finally, we just need to check that the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ is self-adjoint. What this means is that for any two functions $f$, $g$ we have that $\langle \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2},g\rangle = \langle f,\frac{d^2g}{dx^2} \rangle$. This can be done by integration by parts:

$$\int_{0}^{L} f''(x)g(x) dx = - \int_{0}^{L} f'(x)g'(x) dx = \int_{0}^{L} f(x)g''(x) dx$$ where we have thrown away the boundary terms because the boundary conditions tell us that they are zero.

Hence, the operator $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ is self-adjoint, and so the spectral theorem tells us that its eigenvectors form a basis for our function space, so for any given $t$ we can express *any* chosen function as $$f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \varphi_n(x) G_n(t)$$ Thus, we haven't lost any solutions in that we can write the equation like this.
I have skipped a few technical issues here: I haven't told you what the Hilbert space is, and when I say 'any' function, I really mean 'any square-integrable' function. But I don't think these technicalities are important in the understanding.

---

As a fun extra, now that we have our inner product, we can use it to simply derive the coefficients in our series solution. We write our solution as $$f(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \varphi_n(t) G_n(x)$$ and now lets take the inner product of $f$ with the basis element $\varphi_n(x)$. This gives us

$$\langle f(x,0), \varphi_n(x) = \langle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \varphi_k(x) G_k(0), \varphi_n(x) \rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} G_k(0) \langle \varphi_k(x) , \varphi_n(x) \rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} G_k(0) \langle \varphi_k(x) , \varphi_n(x) \rangle $$

Here we have interchanged integration and summation. Finally, the orthonormality of the basis $\{\varphi_k(x)\}$ means that all of the terms but one are zero, so we get $$ \langle f(x,0), \varphi_n(x) = G_n(0) $$ Recall that $G_n(t) = B_n e^{-k\frac{n\pi}{L}^2 t}$, so $B_n = G_n(0)$ and writing our inner product formula in terms of an integral, we get $$\int_{0}^{L} f(x,0) \varphi_n(x) dx = \int_{0}^{L} f(x,0) \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) dx $$ which is our usual expression for the series coefficients!

Answer (score 11):

The method of separation of variables derives from the symmetries of the equation, refer e.g. W. Miller's book *Symmetry and Separation of Variables* (out of print, but available [here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Emille003/separationofvariables.html).)

Separation of variables for nonlinear equations is treated by Victor A. Galaktionov, Sergey R. Svirshchevskii in their book *Exact Solutions and Invariant Subspaces of Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations*, Chapman and Hall/CRC 2007.