# A complete Riemannian metric for which the Ricci flow has no solution

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

What is an example of a connected complete Riemannian manifold such that the Ricci flow has no solution with the given Riemannian metric as initial data? As Terry Tao points out, it is easy to construct an example if you don't assume the manifold is connected.

Comment: I don't know why. I read the paper "Ricci deformation of the metric on complete noncompact kahler manifolds" by Shi Wanxiong, and he said one can find this example. I am just interesting that the Ricci flow has no solution.    What I know is that this example has unbound curvature since if it has bound curvature, Shi constructed a solution; and has no non-negative complex sectional curvature since the work of Wilking. @WillJagy

Comment: @WillJagy There is a theorem stating that one can find a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold s/t the Ricci flowhas no solution,  so I assume the OP is trying to find such an example.

Comment: Can you quote the paper of that kind of theorems? Thank you. @SanathDevalapurkar

Comment: If you allow disconnected manifolds, this is easy, as one can just take the disjoint union of infinitely many spheres whose radii are going to zero (so each one blows up at a time that goes to zero also).  Presumably one can join the spheres together by thin necks in order to obtain a connected example; or maybe one can take an infinitely long cylinder that is slowly tapering to zero.  If the surface contains arbitrarily small minimal immersed spheres, then this paper of Colding-Minicozzi should do the trick: http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/math.AP/0308090 .  There may be an easier way though.

Comment: I think the point of @Will Jagy's comment merely was to ask for context and motivation and/or to critique the use of an imperative. In any case it could help if intent of comments was made more clear. (There is some reason for the 15 character minimum.)

Comment: Why are there 4 votes to close this?

Comment: Please do not close this. The question comes up naturally when one tries to pin down conditions under which the short time existence is true. As far as I know this is far from settled.

Comment: 3 of the votes came from the review process: http://mathoverflow.net/review/close/20382  The question could use a little help from someone with both domain knowledge and English skill.

Comment: OK. I rewrote it. I hope it's OK. If not, please edit, replace, or suggest revisions.

Answer (score 9):

I think this question depends on the precise definition of "initial" metrics.

In the bounded curvature case, thanks to Shi's estimate, an initial metric can be well-defined by smooth convergence, i.e., a metric $g(0)$ is said to be an initial metric of the Ricci flow $g(t),t>0,$ if $g(t)\to g(0)$ in $C_{loc}^\infty$-topology.

However, when we consider the nonexistence problem and manifolds with unbounded curvature, the definition of an initial metric is not uniquely defined.

There are at least two cases one can conceive:

1. $g(0)$ is complete, $Rm(0)$ is pointwise bounded but not uniformly bounded.(See following comments for more precise descriptions.)
   In this case, we have more general existence results than Shi, proven firstly by Deane Yang in https://eudml.org/doc/82313 (Thm 9.2) and then by Guoyi Xu in http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.5604v3.pdf (Cor 1.2) They showed that bounded curvature is not a necessary condition for solutions to exist. The convergence is still smooth here.
2. $g(0)$ is incomplete, say $Rm(0)$ is pointwise bounded except at one point.
   Felix Schulze and Miles Simon constructed expanding solitons coming out from certain "cones". http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.1408.pdf. They showed the Gromov-Hausdorff distance of $g(t)$ and $g(0)$ goes to zero as $t\to 0$ and took this as the definition of initial metric. For an expanding soliton $g(t)$ of general type, the optimal convergence on regular portions is $C_{loc}^{1,\alpha}$(instead of $C_{loc}^\infty$) even both the curvature and volume behave very well. (This can be derived by using harmonic coordinates).

So, to prove a manifold $(M,g)$ admits no short-time solution, we need to indicate which convergence is involved. For example, $(M,g)$ might not be a $C_{loc}^{1,\alpha}$ initial data but indeed a $C^{0}$ initial data for some solutions.

Let's go back to the original question: how to find a manifold (with unbounded curvature) such that NO Ricci flow can converge to it in ANY sense?

It is obvious that we should replace "ANY" by a specfic term like "Gromov-Hausdorff" before we go further. Even in this case, it is not easy to check, for example, Terry Tao's intuitive example is the one we want. (This is probably due to my poor math ability...)

Actually, Thomas Richard and I constructed an example related to this goal. We found a complete manifold (a rotationally symmetric infinite cusp) which is the last time slice of a Ricci flow $g(t)$. That is, we constructed a Ricci flow $g(t)$ which exists only up to time $T$ and $g(T)$ is a complete smooth metric. In this sense we can say that no solution could flow out from our $(M,g(T))$ *as a continuation*. But we still don't know can there be a solution, although not a continuation of $g(t)_{t\leq T}$, defining on $t>T$ and converging to $g(T)$ in certain sense when $t\to T$. Our example is similar to Terry's suggestions, however, I haven't conceive a way to show it is "unflowable". In fact, I can imagine a solution flows out from such cusp, hence I guess this question might be harder than people expected. (The difference between "un-continuable" and "unflowable" should be noted.)

Edit: More words about Xu's work are added. Some stupid typos are fixed. The last paragraph is revised.

Edit:(9 June) Add a reference (Deane Yang's article). I apologize for missing this pioneer work at the first time.

Comment: Hmm, the answer may indeed hinge on exactly what the notion of solution is - if one allows solutions that grow arbitrarily fast at infinity, there may well be no non-compact connected solutions, as was the case with the heat equation when I asked a similar question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72195/unconditional-nonexistence-for-the-heat-equation-with-rapidly-growing-data

Comment: Thank you for this nice comment! According to the answer of your post there, which says in certain sense that "solutions always exist", I guess that it is really not easy to find an example we want for the Ricci flow.

Comment: When you say "pointwise bounded" do you mean that the bound is the same at all points?

Comment: I also don't understand the description "$Rm(0)$ is pointwise bounded but not uniformly bounded". Looking at Xu's paper, he proves a local existence under assumptions that don't require the sectional curvature to have a uniform pointwise bound. The theorem is not a generalization of Shi's, because Xu's proof (like mine) requires a uniform bound on the "local Sobolev constant".

Comment: For "pointwise bounded", I mean "bounded at every point by different values". For instance, $x^2$ is pointwise bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, but no uniform bound can be found. Therefore, a complete manifold with smooth (or at least $C^2$) metric has pointwise bounded $Rm$. (Is this not a usual terminology? sorry about unclearness.)
For Xu's result, in the terminology explained above, he assumes pointwise bound on the curvature. The result I mentioned is Corollary 1.2 in page 3, there he said that the condition of Sobolev constant can be replaced by assuming Ricci curvature bounded from below.

Comment: @Chih-WeiChen: the way you phrase Xu's result is strange. What you call a pointwise bound on $Rm(0)$ is not an assumption because as you say it is alsways true. Why mention it? On the other hand, Xu's corollary 1.2 assumes a lower bound on Ricci plus some integral curvature bound. Not sure why you do not state it. Anyway, thank you for the answer!

Comment: Thank you Igor for your kind comment. In the beginning I just thought that Xu's precise result is not crucial for this post, and the focus is the convergence type at $t=0$. So I cited it quite unceremoniously. I agree with you that it would be better if I wrote the answer more carefully (both in phrase and in math), in particular I should indicate which Corollary I use. 
On the other hand, the reason that I didn't mention the assumptions of Xu ($Ric$ bounded from below and $Rm$ has averaged integral bound) is because both these conditions follow trivially from Shi's assumption ($Rm$ bounded).