# Solution to Heat Equation By Projection

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, heat-equation

Let $X\subseteq C(\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty))$ be the collection of all solutions to the IV heat equation
$$
\partial_t u(t,x) = \partial^2 u(t,x) \qquad u(0,x)=p(0,x),
$$
for some fixed $p\in C^2(\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty);(0,\infty))$.  By standard methods one finds a candidate solution of the form
$$
u=K\star p(0,\cdot);
$$
where $K$ is the heat Kernel.  However, since the domain is unbounded the the maximum principle fails and there may be more than one such solution.

Therefore, is there a solution $\hat{u}$ to the IV heat equation which minimizes the metric-like projection:
$$
\sup_{(x,t) \in [-M,M]^d\times [0,\infty)} \|
  u(t,x)- p(t,x)
\|,
$$
where $M>0$ and where
$$
\sup_{(x,t) \in [-M,M]^d\times [0,\infty)} \|
p(t,x)
\|<\infty
$$

Comment: If there is any such solution, it is automatically a minimizer. Indeed: the difference of any two solutions is a solution of the heat equation with zero initial data, and hence it is either unbounded or identically zero.

Comment: But p does not solve the heat equation so the difference $u-p$ is not a solution to the heat equatoin, in general.

Comment: I mean: if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are solutions and both $u_1-p$ and $u_2-p$ are bounded, then $u_1-u_2$ is a bounded solution with zero initial data, and hence $u_1=u_2$.

Comment: If you want to project, you should minimize instead of maximize, right? To clarify: $p(t,x)$ is given and you want to find $u\in X$ which minimizes the distance $\|u-p\|$? (Which norm, by the way…)

Comment: The fact that $p$ is completely arbitrary as a function of $t$ seems a strange feature of the set-up. For example, for many $p$'s the supremum will just be infinite for any $u$.

Comment: We can assume that $p$ has finite sup and that it is strictly non-negatively valued.

Comment: @N00ber: Your edit changes nothing: every "unusual" solution will grow even faster. See [this article](http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/msb6410) by Tychonoff, and [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/72219/108637) by George Lowther.

Comment: Fair enough, then I will restrict the supremum to a compact set.  This takes care of the problem.